# How to create a Map from YAML configuation in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I want to create a map of type Map> in spring boot , below is the thing i configured in my application.yml and related java class

```
labels:
  nodetypes:
    payment:
      - customerId
      - emailId
      - movileNumber
    profile:
    loyality:

@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "labels")
@Component
public class NodeTypeToResponseProps {

    Map<String, List<String>> nodetypes = new HashMap<>();
}
```

but map is not creating , i am expecting , a map will get created with below data in it

```
{payment : [customerId,emailId,movileNumber] ,profile:[] ,loyality:[] }
```

any help on this please ?

Comment: Did you enable it `@EnableConfigurationProperties`?

Comment: is it mandatory to add this ?

Comment: sorry my mistake the newest spring version dont need it and scan it by default. (Which version you use?) Maybe its a setter/getter problem. Could you add your getter/setter by yourself instead of lombok and test it again .... than it works for me

Comment: spring boot 2.1.6

Comment: okay i tested it now with 2.1.6 everything works (with lombok). Could you try it with your own getter/setter instead of lombok that we can be sure, that is not a lombok problem.

Comment: I tried with spring-boot `2.1.7.RELEASE` and lombok `1.18.8` version - not able to replicate the issue - it's working. which versions are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone , who tried to help me in solving the issue , i found the solution for this  plugin in my build.gradle

```
id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '3.8.4'
```

it is working fine now .

Answer (score -1):

You have to create Arraylists int this YAML configuration which has the name of the attributes. Than your essential able to call your Object by only calling the attribute.

Example:

```
    YamlConfiguration yaml = new YamlConfiguration();
    HashMap<String, List<String>> nodetypes = new HashMap<>();
    //setter
    for(String key :nodetypes.keySet()) 
        yaml.set("path."+key,  nodetypes.get(key));
        yaml.set("path."+new String("keys"), nodetypes.keySet());



    //getter
    HashMap<String, List<String>> cp = new HashMap<>();

    for(String key:yaml.getStringList("path."+new String("keys")))
        cp.put(key, yaml.getStringList("path."+key));
```

Answer (score -3):

You can trying put `@Component` before that `@ConrigurationProerties`